# Check to see if Visual Studio can load an assembly

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, assemblies

I have some user controls that are going to get added into SharePoint through SmartPart.

I'm testing on my local machine, but I'm planning on using the SharePoint security.

I was wondering if there was a way I could to a quick test to see if the Microsoft.SharePoint assembly can actually get loaded so I can continue to test on my machine, then just enable that when I get it uploaded to the server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly copy the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll to your local machine and have a reference to that DLL. However it will only be useful to provide Intellisense. You won't be able to execute any SharePoint code on your local machine with it as SharePoint code only runs on the server. (Another option is to use remote debugging but believe me, it's painful!)

Have a read of [How to Build a SharePoint Development Machine](http://weblogs.asp.net/erobillard/archive/2007/02/23/build-a-sharepoint-development-machine.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I have a server machine built up, but I have all my files local.

I found a quick solution to my problem by creating a module that handles the sharepoint issues that I just comment out when it's not on the server.